# TS conditional type to only extend one item from a union

Tags: typescript

I wish to create a function, which accepts as an input the key from an interface `Foo`, restricted only to keys of `Foo` for which `string` is an acceptable assignment

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b?: string;
  c?: string | boolean;
}

test("a");
test("b"); // Argument of type '"b"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
test("c"); // Argument of type '"c"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)

function test<K extends keyof Foo>(key: Foo[K] extends string ? K : never) {}
```

The above (with strict mode on) fails for `b` and `c` - is there a way to use `extends string` (or similar) 
without having to match the type of the property *exactly*? I am not interested in other potential types, only that the type *could* be a `string`

Comment: `string extends Foo[K]` is what you mean then, not `Foo[K] extends string`

Comment: @jcalz depends if he want string literal types to be included ..

Comment: @jcalz well shit, that does fix it lol. Could you explain the difference as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the test you're apparently looking for is `string extends Foo[K]` and not `Foo[K] extends string`:

```
function test<K extends keyof Foo>(key: string extends Foo[K] ? K : never) {}

test("a"); // okay
test("b"); // okay
test("c"); // okay
```

If you are thinking in terms of assignability, `T extends U` means that a value of type `T` can be assigned to a variable of type `U`.  If you translate "properties of `Foo` for which `string` is an acceptable assignment" into "a value of type `string` can be assigned to the property of `Foo` indexed by key `K`" you get `string extends Foo[K]`.  In such cases if you had a variable `foo` of type `Foo`, a variable `k` of type `K`, and a variable `s` of type `string`, you should be able to write `foo[k] = s` and have it compile.

The test `Foo[K] extends string` would be if you were looking for properties of `Foo` which can be assigned *to* a variable of type `string`, which is the opposite: you'd be able to write `s = foo[k]`.

---

This also correctly rejects non-`string` properties:

```
interface Foo {
  d: number;
}

test("d"); // error!
// Argument of type '"d"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

And it rejects properties of types *narrower* than `string`:

```
interface Foo {
  e: "specificString";
}

test("e"); // error!
// Argument of type '"e"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

You couldn't write `foo.e = s` for any old string `s`, so that's why this is rejected.  (If you need this to be accepted then you're asking for something more complicated to express, and it's also not clear why one would need that... since you would neither be able to read nor write a `string` value in such cases)

---

Also note that `test` does not seem to need to be generic... you could make a generic type alias like:

```
type KeysAssignableFrom<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: V extends T[K] ? K : never
}[keyof T];
```

which will take types `T` and `V` and return the keys of `T` whose properties are assignable from `V`.  Then `test()` becomes:

```
function testConcrete(key: KeysAssignableFrom<Foo, string>) {}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
// function testConcrete(key: "a" | "b" | "c"): void
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJwBcyAzmFKAOYDc+yARgPwnmUi30ItkXXIAfRpgA2EOCDoEAJiRABXALYNoU5BBIAiUgAcICYDGAIAynw6a6AX1y4Y8kAjDB0IZJHIAeANLqAHpAg0qTIANYQAJ7oMGiYAHwAFOERrOZU-oHBsegA2t4AushMyL5yEABu0ACUODa4HmAJmnCaVTTIAPQdyOihcBH1EORNDK3tXT19Aw1NCGOd3b39tjOa0vMT0FDoUACEuBMAglBUShDgPTFgEXrIAORrmnfIwCEg6GCEpKTAVCBwDDE7iwOjgUDgiggkCgl3cNxQdxAFWgdwAdCsho1NBANt0tjt9kcTmcLtE4bcHjjnq9kO9PnBvr9-oCUGAQWCIVDoLDrhSkZUoGiVvCSpFSIdGX8AWJUNtFJ4ACoAGmQADU4sgALw4eh5F5uZJkhX5AC0PFVGXOWQVeUKxVKtORUFwVhyhpixrodgcThcbgaAGFXAgoFykpESN4xRKflKWbL0PKMOgVWxqHEatgbBN7I5nK53Jig45Q5BwylkM1NIJK6Ma5o5lUSOV0MBpLYgA)